# php xpath with dom how to write shorter querys

Tags: php, xml, xpath

The xml file that I need to get out data is large and has lot of inner children in children. The XML on what I need to query looks like in the picture and it has more Ref children in company.
[xml structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mds0s.png)

I need to get the company node that has the correct Info->ID. That node has 3 Ref nodes and I need to get Date from the one that has the correct Who.

I got this working with this ugly code:

```
$query_pod = "//Seller/Company/Info/ID[ID = 'IV'] | //Seller/Company/Ref/Who[Who = 'VA'] | //Seller/Company/Ref/Date";
foreach ($xpath->query( $query_pod ) as $pod)
{
    $pod_dates = $xpath->query( "//Seller/Company/Ref/Who[Who = 'VA'] | //Seller/Company/Ref/Date", $pod );
    $pod_date = $pod_dates->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

I tryed it shorter but I cant get the select element in [] like this:

```
$query_pod = "//Seller/Company/Info[ID = 'IV']";
foreach ($xpath->query( $query_pod ) as $pod)
{
    $pod_dates = $xpath->query( "//Seller/Company/Ref/Date[Who = 'VA'], $pod );
    $pod_date = $pod_dates->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Can someone help? I'm new to xpath.

Comment: $pod_dates = $xpath->query( "//Seller/Company/Ref/Date[Who = 'VA']", $pod ); there are no errors or write mistakes in my real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You second expression (the on inside the loop) does not depend on the context. A slash (`/`) at the begin of a location path means that is absolute, it starts at the document node. `[]` are conditions that filter the result from the previous location path. They are full Xpath expression themselves. So no, it is not always possible to shorten the Xpath expressions. But in you case you can fetch the company node as a list and then the details directly using `DOMXpath::evaluate()`. Unlike `DOMXpath::query()`, `DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return node lists or scalar values. It depending on the expression.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<Seller>
  <Company>
    <Info> 
      <ID>123</ID>
      <Address>Some street, somewhere</Address>
    </Info>
    <Ref>
      <Who>456</Who>
      <Date>2017-01-05T01:59Z</Date>
    </Ref>
  </Company>
</Seller>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/Seller/Company[Info/ID = "123"]') as $company) {
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(Info/ID)', $company),
    $xpath->evaluate('string(Ref/Date)', $company)
  );
}
```

Output:

```
string(3) "123"
string(17) "2017-01-05T01:59Z"
```

If you only need a single value you can fetch it directly:

```
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/Seller/Company[Info/ID = "123"]/Ref/Date)')
);
```

Comment: Had a lot of work so tested this and it does not work. It does not even awnser my question. My XML has more than 1 Ref and the correct date is in the one with who "456". So it should be something like ("Ref [Who = '456']/Date "). But my problem is that it does not even get into the foreach loop.